# Sql query - with order by and without order by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a trouble with a query. Please advise.

```
SELECT Top 10000
'Link' As [Link],
ODST.ID AS [ID],
ODST.Type1 AS [Type 1],
ODST.Type2 AS [Type 2],

COUNT(DISTINCT ODST.Col1) AS [Col 1],
COUNT(DISTINCT ODST.ID) AS [Col 2],
......
......
COUNT(DISTINCT ODST.Col11) AS [Col 11],
SUM(ODST.Col12) AS [Col 12],
.....
.....
SUM([Col35]) AS [Col 35]
FROM ABC ODST
WHERE id in
(Select id from
(select Top 10000 count(*) AS Line, id from ABC WHERE 1=1 
group by id order by Line desc) t2) AND 1=1 
GROUP BY ODST.id, ODST.Type1, ODST.Type2
ORDER BY ODST.Type1, ODST.Type2
```

Above query takes about 7.30 mins to execute in sql management studio. If i remove the Order By clause alone and run, then it runs within a minute. What this means? The table ABC contains millions of records.

10k id's will be returned to the outer query, each of the id can have more than one line. From that, i am selecting the 10k rows again in the outer query. This query, will it orders the records in ascending and then fetches the query or fetches the records and perform order by???

How to improve the performance in this query? is there anything am i missing out here? Please advise on this.

Index is there in the table for the columns Type1, Type2 and ID and all three columns are varchar(50) datatype.

Thanks
venkat

Comment: Ordering on a varchar field will be costly especially on a resultset of several million

Comment: That it is fast without the order by makes sense because processing stops after yuo have  retrieved your 10k records. The Order by makes it necessary to sort _all_ records (millions) on alphnumeric fields. That _will_ take time.

Comment: Top 10k works after sorting :)

Comment: so it sorts first across million records in the table and then selects 10k records. is there any way to tune up the query to improve performance in this?

Answer (score 0):

Two possible reasons I can think of. One would be that when you don't use Order By the engine uses a good index for this query. When you add the Order By it either decides to do a table scan or uses a less favorable index. If this is the case looking at the two execution plans should give you good idea of what's going on and how to proceed.

A bit less likely is that it's not a large table but a large result set? The order by may add a sort of the result causing the extra time.

Comment: But, ideally my query should return the same result if or not i am putting the order by, am i right? if i put order by, records will be sorted, else, not sorted. but, without order by fetches me some more records than with order by. dont know how to figure out its way of querying.

Comment: Would return the same set of rows, but would add the execution time of possibly having to both create a temporary set and having to sort it. But confused. You say you get a _different_ set of records when you ad the order by? That should not happen at all. Only guess would be to notice that you have "top 10000" in a subquery. Would not expect the subquery to affect the final set, but might in some weird way?

Comment: Oh wait. You have two Order By's. Is the Order By you are changing the main one at the bottom one or the one higher up in the subquery? If it is the one in the subauery could definitely affect your selection.

Comment: i am changing the order by which is in the outer query and not in the sub query. if i run the sub query across the table which contains 2 million records, am able to get it in ~30 secs.
answer is Order by change in Outer query, not in inner/sub query

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server uses temporary table to sort result for you because of result size. Millions of rows is too much to do this in-memory. So HDD access slows your query.

Comment: Try to reduce number of result rows and you will see that SQL Server sorting rows in memory and there is no such delay...